# nginx file_put_contents permission denied

Tags: php

I have a problem.
I use this box 'rasmus/php7dev',it works,no problem,But problem so...

system use nginx as default.
When I created a directory named 'apix' via vagrantfile.
it creates 'apix directory' in /usr/share/nginx/html

```
sudo touch /usr/share/nginx/html/index.php
```

run above code on terminal.

```
<?php 
file_put_contents('foo.php',[]);

it does not work..
Warning: file_put_contents(foo.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/default/apix/index.php on line 3
```

to solve it
  sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/share/nginx/html/apix

but the result is false!!!!!

what can I do?

Answer (score 3):

If permissions on apix directory is ok, check that you try to write in apix directory. For example, put whole path - file_put_contents('/usr/share/nginx/html/apix/foo.php',[]);
May be you just write from wrong dir.

Comment: hi...! thanks for your reply.I solved trouble...So that the problem is belonging to vagranfile.. config.vm.synced_folder "apix", "/usr/share/nginx/html/apix", :group => "www-data", :mount_options => ['dmode=775','fmode=664']

Answer (score -1):

If others are getting these kind of errors, you have to make certain that every directory under the `/usr/share/nginx/html` directory should have `chmod`ed with 777.

You can do this by first `cd` to `/usr/share/nginx/html`

```
cd /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Then you have to run:

```
chmod 777 -R *
```

Done.

And for the sake of completeness, If you are getting the below error (which is/was my real problem and google took me here wrong) from the `/var/log/nginx/error.log` then the commands I mentioned above can help you out.

> 2017/07/08 16:57:27 [error] 24573#0: *192 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(file): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /usr/share/nginx/html/agentwebsite/index.php on line 106" while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: example.com, request: "POST /agentwebsite/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com"

### UPDATE:

Maybe I was wrong. but anyway you can follow the better approach:
You should rather create a user group containing the `nginx` and `php` users, and set that group as the owner of the directory and then do `chmod g+srwx` on those files.

Comment: `chmod 777` is never the right answer. You should rather create a user group containing the nginx and php users, and set that group as the owner of the directory and then do `chmod g+srwx`. See also [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318885).

Comment: chmod 777 is really a last resort when you don't know what to do.